# GoogleMaps multiple map directions and PAN

Tags: php, xml, google-maps-api-3

I have built a directions list for users to print.

The problem is that there is a pan function that zooms each direction into turn in question. Every attempt to make this function trigger automatically has failed and at the moment there is a button marked test by each direction that shows were it is on the map. Directions are loaded in using a PHP XML Feed.

[Example](http://www.golfbrowser.com/A4/directions.php?start=S173NE&end=SL42ES).

This is the pan function

```
function tito(colat, colong, section) {
        section.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(colat, colong));
        section.setZoom(14);
}
```

I think it may be that the function is triggered to early, so I tried timeout functions to no avail. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the call:

```
tito("53.3269400", "-1.5168300", "map4")
```

should instead be:

```
tito("53.3269400", "-1.5168300", map4)
```

Your function expects the third argument to be the map object but you are passing it a string.

Comment: Didn't solve it. I have kept it in anyway just in case in your restructured style. In any case keeping the on click event on the link, hiding the link and applying this Jquery has worked. ODD $('.tito').each(function(){
  $('.tito').click();
  });